# UIPasteboard – Set copied text to expire

Tags: ios, swift, uipasteboard

I have a string that I want to put into `UIPasteboard` and it should expire after 2 minutes

```
UIPasteboard.general.setObjects(objects: [NSItemProviderWriting],
    localOnly: true, 
    expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(120))
```

What should be the value of the `objects` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the interface `NSItemProviderWriting` and its required methods in one of your controller classes.

A very simple implementation could look like where `yourString` contains the string to paste:

```
static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
    return [ kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String ]
}

func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {
    completionHandler(yourString.data(using: .utf8), nil)
    return nil
}
```

You should add `import MobileCoreServices` for importing the definition of  `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText`.

Typically, for this implementation you use the controller which makes the call in your example code above. Then, you should use this as as value in the array:

```
UIPasteboard.general.setObjects(objects: [ self ],
    localOnly: true, 
    expirationDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 120))
```

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Swift doesn't seem to know about `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` and 2) where is `yourString` coming from in `loadData`? Is that assumed I'm assigning the string to a local variable on my VC?

Comment: The [UTI types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) are defined in the framework `MobileCoreServices`. The variable `yourString` is just a placeholder for the text to paste. You should define it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

you can you `UIPasteboard.general.setItems`

```
        let expireDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(120))
        
        UIPasteboard.general.setItems([[UIPasteboard.typeAutomatic: value]],
                options: [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate: expireDate])
```